# console.log() in Firefox 54.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, console.log

I've recently updated to Firefox 54.0, and now the Webconsole *isn't working anymore.*

When trying to type `console.log(5)` in the Webconsole, nothing happens...  I get the following result.

[image: console.log in firefox]

In chromium it still works, there I get the following.

[image: console.log in chromium]

Any idea's why this happened and how I can get `console.log()` working again in FF? (Is this a bug? Should I report it?)

OS: Elementary OS Loki

#### Edit

[image: debug]

Comment: use string console.log("5") or variable var F = 5; console.log(F)

Comment: if you type in 'console' and press enter. What do you get back? is it some sort of function?

Comment: yes, it's is the repl function that returns the result of the call, which is `undefined`

Comment: Do you have the "Logging" option turned on? If I turn mine off I get what you get.

Comment: Perhaps the javascript filter defaults changed. What happens when you type `console.error(5)`?

Comment: @matt: I've added the result of the `console`command. The 'Logging" option? Where can I find that? Also the command `console.error(5)` seems to return 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have the logging turned off. To enable it click on the "Logging" button in the toolbar.

[image: Toolbar]

Comment: Okay, thanks :) Strange how the updated disabled this.